# String Search and format in C

Tags: c, string, search, buffer

Just a quick one: in C I have a buffer full of data like below:

```
char buffer[255]="CODE=12345-MODE-12453-CODE1-12355"
```

My question is how to search through this. For example for the `CODE=12345`, section bear in mind that the numbers change, so I would like to search like this `CODE=*****` using wildcard or preset amount of spaces after the `CODE=` part.

This method wont compile last one left to try

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main ()
{
    char buf[255]="CODE=12345-MODE-12453-CODE1-12355";

#define TRIMSPACES(p) while(*p != '\0' && isspace((unsigned char)*p) != 0) ++p 
#define NSTRIP(p, n) p += n 
#define STRIP(p) ++p 

char* getcode(const char *input) 
{ 
  char *p = (char*) input, *buf, *pbuf; 

  if((buf = malloc(256)) == NULL) 
    return NULL; 

  pbuf = buf; 
  while(*p != '\0') { 
    if(strncmp(p, "CODE", 3) == 0) { 
      NSTRIP(p, 4); //remove 'code' 
      TRIMSPACES(p);//trim white-space after 'code' 

     if(*p != '=')  
       return NULL; 

      STRIP(p); // remove '=' 
      TRIMSPACES(p); //trim white-spaces after '=' 

/* copy the value until found a '-'  
   note: you must be control the size of it,  
   for avoid overflow. we allocated size, that's 256 
   or do subsequent calls to realloc() 
*/ 
      while(*p != '\0' && *p != '-') 
    *pbuf ++ = *p++; 

    //  break; 
    } 
    p ++; 
  } 

//put 0-terminator. 
  *pbuf ++ = '\0'; 

  return buf; 
} 




//   
}
```

Comment: Did you really mean to have an = after CODE, but hyphens after MODE and CODE1?  Doesn't seem a consistent notation....

Answer (score 3):

You could use the sscanf() function:

```
int number;
sscanf(buffer, "CODE = %i", &number);
```

for that to work well your buffer has to be null terminated.

Comment: This doesn't "search" - it only matches if `CODE=<number>` appears at the very start of the buffer.

Comment: In case that is not guaranteed one can use strstr() to locate a substring that starts with "CODE" and apply sscanf to that buffer location.

Comment: Yes, but not quite so simply - you also need to check that the character before the `strstr` match is either the first or a hyphen.  (Also, you should check ala `if (sscanf(...) == 1)` or you've no idea if the `sscanf` matched....)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `CODE=` part always comes at the beginning of the string, it's pretty easy:

```
sscanf(buffer, "CODE = %d", &number);
```

...but you want `buffer` to be `char[255]`, not `unsigned long`.

Edit: If the `CODE=` part isn't necessarily at the beginning of the string, you can use `strstr` to find `CODE` in the buffer, do your sscanf starting from that point, then look immediately following that:

```
int codes[256];
char *pos = buffer;
size_t current = 0;

while ((pos=strstr(pos, "CODE")) != NULL) {
     if (sscanf(pos, "CODE = %d", codes+current))
         ++current;
     pos += 4;
}
```

Edit2: 
For example, you'd use this something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main ()
{
    // This is full of other junk as well 
    char buffer[255]="CODE=12345 MODE-12453 CODE=12355" ; 
    int i;
    int codes[256]; 
    char *pos = buffer; 
    size_t current = 0; 

    while ((pos=strstr(pos, "CODE")) != NULL) { 
        if (sscanf(pos, "CODE = %d", codes+current)) 
            ++current; 
        pos += 4; 
    } 

    for (i=0; i<current; i++)
        printf("%d\n", codes[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

For me, this produces the following output:

```
12345
12355
```

...correctly reading the two "CODE=xxx" sections, but skipings over the "MODE=yyy" section.

Comment: Thanks I changed the buffer however the code comes in the middle of the string all over the output buffer is from a USB device so the strings are all over the buffer.
So I was only able to return the first string.

Comment: Sorry think I edited your post above however this doesnt return any of the numbers now. Also I notice some code are not just code=12345 some have tails as well like code=12345-001 is this an issue also.

Comment: The text "CODE" can not be constant in the loop... you might reasonably address that with an array of `const char*` indexed on `current` (having a hardcoded list of identifiers to drive the iteration also prevents buffer overruns), but you'll need to search from buffer each time, and check `strstr()` found the first character or one preceeded by a hyphen.

Comment: @user1539199: It sounds to me like you need to define a bit better what you're really after. Is it `arbitrary string followed by "=", followed one or more numbers, separated by dashes`?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it instead of `sscanf()`:

```
 char *input, *code;

  input = strstr(buf, "CODE");
  if(input == NULL) {
    printf("Not found CODE=\n");
    return -1;
  }

  code = strtok(strdup(input), "=");
  if(code != NULL) {
    code = strtok(NULL, "-");
    printf("%s\n", code); // code = atoi(code);
  } else {
    //not found '='
  }
```

Or more robust way.. a bit more complex:

```
    #define TRIMSPACES(p) while(*p != '\0' && isspace((unsigned char)*p) != 0) ++p
    #define NSTRIP(p, n) p += n
    #define STRIP(p) ++p

    char* getcode(const char *input, size_t limit)
{
    char *p = (char*) input, *buf, *pbuf;
    size_t i = 0;

    while(*p != '\0') {
        if(strncmp(p, "CODE", 3) == 0) {

        NSTRIP(p, 4); //remove 'code'
        TRIMSPACES(p);//trim all white-spaces after 'code'

        /* check we have a '=' after CODE (without spaces).
           if there is not, returns NULL
        */
        if(*p != '=') 
            return NULL;

        /* ok. We have.. now we don't need of it
            just remove it from we output string.
        */
        STRIP(p);

        /* remove again all white-spaces after '=' */
        TRIMSPACES(p);

        /* the rest of string is not valid,
            because are white-spaces values.
        */
        if(*p == '\0')
            return NULL;

        /* allocate space for store the value
            between code= and -.
            this limit is set into second parameter.
        */
        if((buf = malloc(limit)) == NULL)
            return NULL;

    /* copy the value until found a '-' 
        note: you must be control the size of it, 
       for don't overflow. we allocated 256 bytes.
        if the string is greater it, do implementation with
        subjecents call to realloc()
    */
     pbuf = buf;
      while(*p != '\0' && *p != '-' && i < limit) {
        *pbuf ++ = *p++; 
        i ++;
    }

      *pbuf ++ = '\0';
      return buf;
    }
    p ++;
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

And then:

```
char buf[255] = "foo baa CODE =     12345-MODE-12453-CODE-12355";
char *code = getcode(buf,256);

if(code != NULL) {
    printf("code = %s\n", code);
    free(code);
} else {
    printf("Not found code.\n");
}
```

output:

> code = 12345

Check out this [`online`](http://codepad.org/yAZyzmiz).

if you want to don't differentiate case, you can use the [`strncasecmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strcasecmp.html) that's  POSIX function.

Comment: Thanks for the 2 methods I tried both the top returns 12345 MODE so wrong way around then say I change it to mode it returns null. The 2nd one wont compile throws up 3 errors which I can seem to work out. :-(

Comment: @user1539199: What input have you tried? what warnings are you getting? but check out the update of `getcode()`. I compiled it by using `gcc-3 -Wall -mno-cygwin foo.c`(the `-mno-cygwin` flag is a cygwin-spefi)  and I get the "expected" output that are the `12345` digits.

Comment: Thanks for the code pad just throws up one error now on line
  if((buf = malloc(limit)) == NULL)
cannot convert void to char** VS2010

Comment: Can you post the error message and compiler that you are using?

Comment: microsoft visual studio 2010 looks like the memory alloc bit void to char error.

Comment: You are compiling a `C` code if like `C++` code. Where you need cast return-value from malloc: `if((buf = (char*)malloc(limit)) == NULL)` but if you can, I recommend change it to compiler as really C code.

Comment: For change it, on VS C++ goto: Project, *you project name* properties, Configuration properties, C/C++, Advanced, search for `compile as` and set it to `compile as C code /Tc`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *getcode(const char *str, const char *pattern){
    //pattern: char is match, space is skip, * is collect
    static const char *p=NULL;
    char *retbuf, *pat;
    int i, match, skip, patlen;
    if(str != NULL) p=str;
    if(p==NULL || *p=='\0') return NULL;
    if(NULL==(retbuf=(char*)malloc((strlen(p)+1)*sizeof(char))))
        return NULL;
    pat = (char*)pattern;
    patlen = strlen(pat);
    i = match = skip = 0;
    while(*p){
        if(isspace(*p)){
            ++p;
            ++skip;
            continue;
        }
        if(*pat){
            if(*p == *pat){
                ++match;
                ++p;
                ++pat;
            } else if(*pat == '*'){
                ++match;
                retbuf[i++]=*p++;
                ++pat;
            } else {
                if(match){//reset
                    pat=(char*)pattern;
                    p -= match + skip -1;
                    i = match = skip = 0;
                } else //next
                    ++p;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i){//has match
        retbuf[i++]='\0';
        retbuf=realloc(retbuf, i);
        return retbuf;
    } else {
        free(retbuf);
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main (){
    char *code;
    code=getcode("CODE=12345-MODE-12453-CODE1-12355", "CODE=*****");
    printf("\"%s\"\n",code);//"12345"
    free(code);
    code=getcode(" CODE = 12345-MODE-12453-CODE1-12355", "CODE=*****");
    printf("\"%s\"\n",code);//"12345"
    free(code);
    code=getcode("CODE-12345-MODE-12453-CODE1-12355", "CODE=*****");
    if(code==NULL)printf("not match\n");//not match
    code=getcode("CODE=12345-MODE-12453-CODE=12355", "CODE=*****");
    printf("\"%s\"\n",code);//"12345"
    free(code);
    code=getcode(NULL, "CODE=*****");
    printf("\"%s\"\n",code);//"12355"
    free(code);
    code=getcode("CODE=12345-MODE-12453-CODE1-12355", "CODE=*****");
    printf("\"%s\"\n",code);//"12345"
    free(code);
    code=getcode(NULL, "CODE1-*****");
    printf("\"%s\"\n",code);//"12355"
    free(code);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your replys got it working fine in the end much appreciated.